# For $1 \leq m \leq n$ there is an element of order $q^m-1$ in $GL_n(\mathbb F_q).$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, field-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

Let $GL_n(\mathbb F_q)$ be the General linear group over a finite field $\mathbb F_q$, where $q$ is any prime power. Then how can I show that for $1 \leq m \leq n$ there is an element of order $q^m-1$ in $GL_n(\mathbb F_q).$

I know that the maximal possible order of an element in $GL_n(\mathbb F_q)$ is $q^n-1,$ which follows from the fact that order of an invertible matrix in $GL_n(\mathbb F_q)$ is same as the order of the minimal polynomial, and order of an irreducible polynomial $f(X) \in \mathbb F_q[X]$ with $f(0) \neq 0$ and $\text {deg}(f)=m$ is same as the order of any (hence all) root of $f$ in $\mathbb F_{q^m}^{\times}.$

In this problem since $\mathbb F_{q^m}$ is not necessarily a subfield of $\mathbb F_{q^n}$ for $1 \leq m \leq n,$ I cannot prove it. I need some help. Thanks.

Comment: For $m=n$ see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624160/gl-n-mathbb-f-q-has-an-element-of-order-qn-1). So the maximal case is solved. The see also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292620/exponent-of-gln-q/294524#294524).

Comment: If $A$ has order $q^m-1$ in $GL_m(\Bbb F_q)$, consider the block matrix $\pmatrix{A&\\&I_{n-m}}$.